# xlrd dynamic variables python

Tags: xlrd

I can make it work like this:

```
book = xlrd.open_workbook(Path+'infile')
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
A, B, C, D = ([] for i in range (4))
A = sheet.col_values(0)
B = sheet.col_values(1)
C = sheet.col_values(2)
D = sheet.col_values(3)
```

but what I want is to make it work like this:

```
dyn_var_list = [A, B, C, D]
assert(len(sheet.row_values(0))==len(dyn_var_list))
for index, col in enumerate(sheet.row_values(0)):
    dyn_var_list[index].append(col)
```

however, so far I can only get one value in my lists, using the code above, which is due to the usage of "(0)" after the row_values I guess, but I don't know how to resolve this as of yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
for c in range(sheet.ncols):
     for r in range(sheet.nrows):
          dyn_var_list[c].append(sheet.cell(r,c).value)
```

Here sheet.nrows gives you the number of rows in the sheet.

Comment: Didn't do the trick. This is as close as I got:
dyn_var_list = [A, B, C, D]
for i in range(len(dyn_var_list)):
 dyn_var_list[i] = first_sheet.col_values(i)

However, now "print(dyn_var_list[1])" prints the first list, but "print(A)" does not (same for B, C and D)